# Retrive credit memo from quickbooks desktop through c# code

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have a requirement wherein i need to retrieve the credit memos from quickbooks desktop (enterprise edition) programatically/ through c# code.

Can anyone help me with this code/method to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use CreditMemoQuery.

See the Onscreen Reference Guide - http://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html or look at the samples for the other requests and modify them.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0050_documentation/sample_code

Comment: I used the above mentioned way, but i just want to retrieve all the credit memo's from Quickbooks. As i am new to quickbooks integration it was difficult for me to understand that CreditMemoQuery(). It would be great if you help me with relevant code to retrieve only credit memo from QB.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ICreditMemoQuery`object to retrieve credit memo list from QuickBooks. Here's a sample C# code to retrieve Credit memo list using QuickBooks SDK 13.0:

```
using QBXMLRP2Lib;
using Interop.QBFC13;

public class SDKApp
{
    private QBSessionManager sessionMgr;

    public SDKApp()
    {
        // in the class constructor - sessionMgr is a member variable
        sessionMgr = new QBSessionManager(); 
    }

    public void GetCreditMemoData()
    {
        // open connection and begin session before data fetch - intentionally skipped this code
        IMsgSetRequest msgset = null;
        ICreditMemoQuery creditMemoQuery = null;
        try
        {
            // during data fetch
            msgset = sessionMgr.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
            creditMemoQuery = msgset.AppendCreditMemoQueryRq();

            creditMemoQuery.ORTxnQuery.TxnFilter.ORDateRangeFilter.ModifiedDateRangeFilter.FromModifiedDate.SetValue(new DateTime(2012, 3, 31), false); // you can apply filters too

            IMsgSetResponse msgRes = sessionMgr.DoRequests(msgset);
            IResponseList responseList = msgRes.ResponseList;
            if (responseList.Count > 0)
            {
                IResponse response = responseList.GetAt(0);
                ICreditMemoRetList creditMemoList = response.Detail as ICreditMemoRetList;
                if (creditMemoList == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i <= creditMemoList.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    ICreditMemoRet qbCreditMemo = creditMemoList.GetAt(i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Credit no.:" + qbCreditMemo.TxnNumber.GetValue() + " Customer:" + qbCreditMemo.CustomerRef.FullName.GetValue() + " Total:" + qbCreditMemo.TotalAmount.GetValue());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception here
        }
        finally
        {
            if (msgset != null)
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(msgset);
            }
            if (creditMemoQuery != null)
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(creditMemoQuery);
            }
        }

        // end session and close connection after data fetch - intentionally skipped this code
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.